# Dynamically add nested Parameters to Alamofire Parameters

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Suppose if have an array of tests and want to dynamically add each test to my request in order to look like the following:

```
 data[Security][check]
 data[Test][%d][Participant][device_id]
 data[Test][%d][Participant][id]
 data[Test][%d][Participant][email]
 data[Test][%d][Participant][firstname]
 data[Test][%d][Participant][lastname]
 data[Test][%d][test_id]
 data[Test][%d][question_id]
 data[Test][%d][answer]
```

where %d is the index of the test in the Array of tests.
How would I go about dynamically constructing this Parameter set inside a for loop?
I guess I cannot use `parameters.updateValue()` since I would need a nested key. But parameters`[Test][<index>][Participant][<device_id>]` is giving me a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a separate `Dictionary<String, Any>`for each layer in the parameters object i.e.

```
var data = Dictionary<String, Any>()
var test = Dictionary<String, Any>()
var index = Dictionary<String, Any>()
var content = Dictionary<String, Any>()
var participant = Dictionary<String, Any>()
//and then fill your dicitionaries from inside to outside
participant.updateValue(1, forKey:"deviceId")
participant.updateValue(12, forKey:"id")
//...
content.updateValue(participant, forKey:"Participant")
content.updateValue(1, forKey:"testId")
//...
index.updateValue(content, forKey: "0")
test.updateValue(index, forKey: "Test")
data.updateValue(test, forKey:"data")
```